# Get DateTime format of Server using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some sample code to get the format,It's not working properly.

```
 string dateString, format;
    DateTime result;
    CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

    // Parse date-only value with invariant culture.
    dateString = System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
    format = "d";
    try
    {
        result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
        Response.Write(result.GetDateTimeFormats()[3]);
        Response.Write(provider);
        Response.Write(format);
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
```

Please help me ? i want to display the Date Format of Server.

Comment: What is the problem exactly ?

Comment: I want to display the format value like "DD/MM/YYYY" instead of  value.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve in the code snippet. I think you should investigate the connection between `CultureInfo` and `DateTimeFormat`. [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat(v=vs.110).aspx) might be a good place to start.

Comment: InvariantCulture is what it says: invariant.  You might look at CultureInfo.CurrentCulture or better CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture, though both can be overridden in code.  You also should define what you mean by "server culture": the default culture can be different for different user accounts on a server.

Comment: That's fine. But Do you have any idea to get the format value?

Comment: Can you help me on "server culture"?Any piece of code do u have?

Comment: @PapunSahoo, I have posted a simple solution to your problem with detailed explanation. Check it out.

Comment: But actually i need to compare the value with current culture and display.

Comment: @PapunSahoo, Then omit the second parameter to the ToString method  in my answer and the current culture date separator will be used.

Comment: @PapunSahoo,  Also, if you are happy with the current culture date format, then use the second code snippet that I have just added to my last answer. It is very simple.

Comment: @Sunil:Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` will give you the short date format of the current culture.

There are more details of the DateTimeFormatInfo class here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want the date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format as you suggested in one of your comments, then simply use the following code.

If you do not use the second parameter in ToString method, then you will not get `/` as date separator but the date separator as defined by current culture in your application which is `-` for default US culture.

```
string formattedDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy",
                                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If all you want is the date part using current culture, then simply use the code below.

```
string  formattedDate = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the format strings from the CultureInfo DateTimeFormat property, which is a DateTimeFormatInfo instance. This in turn has properties like ShortDatePattern and ShortTimePattern, containing the format strings:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CultureInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            string shortUsDateFormatString = us.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
            string shortUsTimeFormatString = us.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
            Response.Write(shortUsDateFormatString);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This program executes the system date time format. Is it in dd/mmm/yyyy or other format and the which cultuerInfo is the system running on.

```
if (Session["ClaimDate"] != null)
                {
                    DateTime day;
                    CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                    DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;
                    string[] SystemDateTimePatterns = new string[250];
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (string name in dtfi.GetAllDateTimePatterns('d'))
                    {
                        SystemDateTimePatterns[i] = name;
                        i++;
                    }
                    string[] myDateTimeFormat = { "dd-MMM-yy", "dd-MMM-yyyy" };

                    if (myDateTimeFormat[0].Equals(SystemDateTimePatterns[0]) || myDateTimeFormat[1].Equals(SystemDateTimePatterns[0]))
                    {
                        day = DateTime.ParseExact(Session["ClaimDate"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        day = DateTime.Parse(Session["ClaimDate"].ToString());
                    }
                    //   DateTime day = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["ClaimDate"].ToString());
                    ddlDay.Items.FindByValue(day.Day.ToString("00")).Selected = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    ddlDay.Items.FindByValue(DateTime.Now.Day.ToString("00")).Selected = true;
                }``
```